# QGIS rendering TIFF color with wrong color

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, color, display

When I try to display a GeoTIFF image with single band pseudocolor, the style seems to be wrong for values out of the range 255.

[image]

The legend is shown as

[image]

**The green pixels have a value larger than 255**. I think the problem might be related with integer range but my GeoTIFF has a data type of int32.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured out the problem. Just quit the software and reload the GeoTIFF image, which seems to be a bug in the software

Comment: If you found a bug in the software please report it: https://issues.qgis.org